# Yii customizing the display of url parameters

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm trying to change the way Yii is showing the url for my "product" page. 
Now, it shows this:

```
   localhost/~antonio/project/?r=site/product&id=HXW1410D260D0TB013&language=en
```

Or with urlFormat=path

```
   localhost/~antonio/project/en/product/id/HXW1410D260D0TB013
```

I need the url's to look like this:

```
   localhost/~antonio/project/en/product/HXW1410D260D0TB013
```

I looked into the Yii docs, but I can't find a way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following rule to your main.php rules array:

```
'product/<id:[A-Z0-9]+>'=>'site/product',
```

so you should have something like

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
                'product/<id:[A-Z0-9]+>'=>'site/product',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
         ),
  ),
```

essentially the rule format is as follows:

```
'product/<id:[A-Z0-9]+>'=>'site/product',
```

Terms in <> mean you are passing a variable, so

```
<id:[A-Z0-9]+>
```

means you are passing $_GET['id'] if the regex matches (if it has only capital letters and numbers).

So the rule above means if the url matches product/something, then send it to site/product and pass the "something" as a $_GET parameter called id.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: alternatively `'product/<id:\w+>'=>'site/product',` might also work

Answer (score 0):

For this, go to `main.php` file in config folder and  uncomment the following to enable URLs in **path** format:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Comment: that won't work because it expects the product id to be a digit, also from the question, he has already enabled the url manager.